# Do you know a way to clean-up heroku/mongohq database?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, rake, mongoid, seed

I'm looking for a way to reset a mongodb deploied on heroku/mongohq, something like 
`# heroku rake db:reset` 
I know that's possible to directly login mongohq and drop it, but I'd like a quick command line.

Thanks in advance 
Luca

Comment: Can you not log into MongoHQ via your Heroku dashboard and drop the database then re-create it from there?

Comment: how do you do it via Heroku dashboard ?

Comment: The only procedure I know is the following: http://support.mongohq.com/discussions/community-tips/2-logging-in-to-mongohq-for-heroku-users ... but is tricky and I'm looking something like "rake db:reset"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your title you say "clean up", in your description you say "reset". You also use the word "drop" as if you want to drop a database.

1. Generally speaking, you don't want to "reset" MongoDB unless there's some server issue.
2. You generally don't want MongoDB to "running dirty", especially in such a way that it needs to be "cleaned up".
3. Generally, dropping a database is either an Admin task or a task associated with some test script you are running

`rake` is a build tool and these are all functions of DB administration.

Would you be able to be more specific about what you're trying to do?

---

Alright, so I found some [more details](http://www.neeraj.name/2008/03/24/rake-db-migrate-reset-vs-rake-db-reset.html). It looks like `rake:reset` does the following:

```
:reset => ['db:drop', 'db:create', 'db:schema:load']
```

So, it does a drop, a create and a schema load. These are all Rails-specific tasks and they're all tied to some specific features of SQL databases.

In general, MongoDB doesn't have a schema, so there's normally no need for `db:create` and `db:schema:load`. So basically you're just doing a `db:drop` (and maybe some `ensureIndex` commands)?

I'm looking at the rest of these rake tasks, and many of them don't really apply to typical MongoDB use cases. If you really want this functionality, you'll probably have to write some of this for yourself.

Comment: I'd like to obtain exatly the same you got running "heroku rake db:reset". Infact, it just works for Heroku/PostgreSQL deploy and not for Heroku/MongoHQ ... The same just happen on a "local" rails app running on mysql or sqlite vs mongodb

Comment: db:drop also drops the users you set up at MongoHQ.